# "Repeated column in mapping for collection" for hibernate ManyToMany with same foreign key?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 4 tables as following:

```
create table market (
    id int(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    market_id varchar(30) unique
);

create table market_channel_group (
    id int(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    market_id varchar(30),
    channel_group_id varchar(30),
    unique index (market_id,channel_group_id)
);

create table market_channel (
    id int(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    market_id varchar(30),
    channel_id varchar(30),
    unique index (market_id,channel_group_id)
);

create table market_channel_group_detail (
    id int(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    market_id varchar(30),
    channel_group_id varchar(30),
    channel_id varchar(30),
    unique index (market_id,channel_group_id, channel_id)
);
```

as you can see, market is OneToMany to market_channel_group, market_channel.
market_channel_group is ManyToMany to market_channel under specific market.

The problem is in my market_channel_group entity, I have following code:

```
@Entity(name = "market_channel_group")
@Table(name = "market_channel_group", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"market_id", "channel_group_id"})})
public class MarketChannelGroup extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MarketChannelGroup() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "market_id", referencedColumnName = "market_id")
    private Market market;

    @Column(name = "channel_group_id", length = 50)
    private String channelGroupId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "market_channel_group_detail",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "market_id", referencedColumnName = "market_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "channel_group_id", referencedColumnName = "channel_group_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "market_id", referencedColumnName = "market_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id", referencedColumnName = "channel_id")})
    private List<MarketChannel> channels;

...
}
```

However, I got this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: MarketChannelGroup.channels column: market_id
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.checkColumnDuplication(Collection.java:343) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
...
```

How should I write the ManyToMany annotation correctly? or is there any problem of my design.

**UPDATE**

*since we will import data from external resource, the auto increment id is not used as other tables' reference, each table has another index other than its own id.*

Comment: Did you solve this? Did you maybe create a Hibernate issue for this?

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was solved by adding `insertable = false, updatable = false` to the the `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: It is working successfully. Thank you!